# Webpart to Show Outlook Calendar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, web-part, outlook

I have been trying and trying but hit a road block.  I am working with SharePoint 2013 and Outlook 365 and want to show an Outlook Calendar in SharePoint.  Simple but no simple.  I cannot get the exchange to work by adding an Outlook Calendar to SharePoint by using the calendar overlay option.  So I want to find another way.  I figure there should be a webpart that will allow a outlook calendar to be shown maybe similar to Page Viewer web part.  Is there such a webpart that can do show an Outlook calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there is a OOB web part can show Exchange Online(outlook 365) calendar in SharePoint 2013 on-premise environment.

There is a outlook web access web part, but when we add the exchange online calendar, it cannot be display with iframe cannot be displayed security error.

It seems that we are not be able to configure server to server trust between SharePoint On-premise with Exchange Online.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have a web part that is not OOB that would recommend that will do what I am trying to do?